# How to split the column of a matrix into two columns?

Tags: r

I have matrix, which one of the columns of it has IDs which sperated with ",". I just want to split that cloumn into two columns s.t each new column just have one part of IDs.
what is the easiest  way to do it ?

My matrix is:

```
> L
     a    u                    
[1,] "10" "mature,MIMAT0000062"
[2,] "20" "stemloop"           
[3,] "40" "mature,MIMAT0000062"
```

and the expected output is :

```
> k
     a    u          v             
[1,] "10" "mature"   "MIMAT0000062"
[2,] "20" "stemloop" "NA"          
[3,] "40" "mature"   "MIMAT0000062"
>
```

**Edit:**

Now I have to split this matrix into two matrix based on the column with "NA" values, one with all "NA" and other without "NA".

Input:

```
>k
       a    u         v
[1,] "10" "mature"    "MIMAT0000062"
[2,] "20" "stemloop"  "NA"
[3,] "40" "mature_2"  "MIMAT0000043"
```

Output should be like,

```
>k1
       a    u         v
[1,] "10" "mature"    "MIMAT0000062"
[2,] "40" "mature_2"  "MIMAT0000043"

>k2
       a    u         v
[1,] "20" "stemloop"  "NA"
```

Comment: See `strsplit` documentation.

Comment: And again, your matrix should probably be a data.frame. A matrix can only hold one type of variable, but you have a mixture of numbers and text.

Comment: I don't get why people downvote a beginner question without thinking twice or leaving a comment.

Comment: Please edit your question so its easy for us to create your data frame  by cutting and pasting some code (one of the replies has already done this for you).

Comment: Can you have `"foo,"` or `",foo"` strings? And if so, do you want an empty string in the respective column or an NA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different way..

```
a <- c(10,20,40)
u <- c("mature,MIMAT0000062", "stemloop", "mature,MIMAT0000062")
L <- data.frame(a,u)     #better use a data.frame


v <- strsplit(as.character(L$u), ",")
L$u <- sapply(v, `[`, 1)
L$v <- sapply(v, `[`, 2)

> L
#   a        u            v
#1 10   mature MIMAT0000062
#2 20 stemloop         <NA>
#3 40   mature MIMAT0000062
```

Comment: `reshape2::colsplit` is very useful for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Spacedman thx for that correction, I had first used the df `test` but changed it later to the name of the OP's example. Apparently I missed that.

Comment: Also, if there's more than one comma in the input column, it drops later parts "three,blind,mice" -> columns with just "three" and "blind". But maybe this can't be valid input (always test edge cases though).

Answer (score 2):

A two liner:

```
L$v =sapply(strsplit(as.character(L$u),","), "[", 2)
L$u =sapply(strsplit(as.character(L$u),","), "[", 1)
#L
#   a        u            v
#1 10   mature MIMAT0000062
#2 20 stemloop         <NA>
#3 40   mature MIMAT0000062
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to change the entries in `u`, correct? when I run it, they remain as before.

Comment: Missed that `u `has to be changed as well, works now

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using `reshape2::colsplit` as joran suggested:

```
library(reshape2)
k = cbind(a =L$a,colsplit(L$u,",",c("u","v")))
#k
#   a   u       v
#1  10  mature  MIMAT0000062
#2  20  stemloop     
#3  40  mature  MIMAT0000062
```

Answer (score 2):

I have [a function called **`cSplit`**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) that is quite fast and deals with these types of problems very easily.

Here are a few examples of the function in use, along with some different cases to consider:

Your existing sample data:

```
M1 <- cbind(a = c(10,20,40), 
            u = c("mature,MIMAT0000062", 
                  "stemloop", "mature,MIMAT0000062"))
cSplit(data.frame(M1), "u", ",")
#     a      u_1          u_2
# 1: 10   mature MIMAT0000062
# 2: 20 stemloop           NA
# 3: 40   mature MIMAT0000062
```

One "u" value with a comma at the start:

```
M2 <- cbind(a = c(10,20,40), 
            u = c(",MIMAT0000062", 
                  "stemloop", "mature,MIMAT0000062"))
cSplit(data.frame(M2), "u", ",")
#     a      u_1          u_2
# 1: 10          MIMAT0000062
# 2: 20 stemloop           NA
# 3: 40   mature MIMAT0000062
```

One "u" value that splits into 3 columns:

```
M3 <- cbind(a = c(10,20,40), 
            u = c("mature,MIMAT0000062", 
                  "stemloop,,something", "mature,MIMAT0000062"))
cSplit(data.frame(M3), "u", ",")
#     a      u_1          u_2       u_3
# 1: 10   mature MIMAT0000062        NA
# 2: 20 stemloop              something
# 3: 40   mature MIMAT0000062        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This works when the values are comma separated:

```
sep_cols = matrix(unlist(strsplit(as.character(L$u), ",")), ncol = 2)
new_L = cbind(L, sep_cols)
```

Comment: but not all of rows of that column have the IDs seprated with ",". for my example, second row of my matrix.

Comment: Well i did't saw that, so i'll edit my answer to make it clear.